# MasterCard Generate AC

Tags: emv, mastercard

I tried to process payment with MasterCard / MIR.
I do read data from VISA successfully after send PDOL, but MS does not requires PDOL.

1st step in transaction:

> Select 2PAY.SYS
>
> [SEND] : 00 A4 04 00 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 00
>
> [READ] : 6F 23 84 0E 32 50 41 59 2E 53 59 53 2E 44 44 46 30 31 A5 11
> BF 0C 0E 61 0C 4F 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 87 01 01 90 00

2nd step:

> [SEND] : 00 A4 04 00 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 00
> F
> [READ] : 6F 44 84 07 A0 00 00 00 04 10 10 A5 39 50 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 5F 2D 04 72 75 65 6E 87 01 01 9F 11 01 01 9F 12 0A 4D 41 53 54 45 52 43 41 52 44 BF 0C 0F 9F 4D 02 0B 0A 9F 6E 07 06 43 00 00 30 30 00 90 00

Card does not requres PDOL

3rd step:

> [SEND] : 80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 00
>
> [READ] : 77 16 82 02 19 80 94 10 08 01 01 00 10 01 01 01 18 01 02 00 20 01 02 00 90 00

Recieved [Application File Locator (AFL)](http://www.emvlab.org/emvtags/show/t94/)

Step 4:

Read all available data.

> [SEND] : 00 B2 01 0C 00
>
> and other sectors

I red all sectors. But there are not tags requires for payment: 9F26 - Application Cryptogram, 9F37 - Unpredictable Number, 9F36 - Transatcion Counter.

To get this tags I could make command Generate AC with CDOL, but how to generate CDOL?
Card says about CDOL1 and CDOL2. And CDOL1 requires tags that card generate itself.

Card answers, contains CDOL1 and CDOL2:

> 70 81 A0 57 13 55 45 46 77 77 25 42 79 D2 01 12 01 58 11 10 00 00 79 0F 5A 08 55 45 46 77 77 25 42 79 5F 24 03 20 11 30 5F 25 03 17 11 01 5F 28 02 06 43 5F 34 01 01 8C 21 9F 02 06 9F 03 06 9F 1A 02 95 05 5F 2A 02 9A 03 9C 01 9F 37 04 9F 35 01 9F 45 02 9F 4C 08 9F 34 03 8D 0C 91 0A 8A 02 95 05 9F 37 04 9F 4C 08 8E 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 42 03 1E 03 1F 03 9F 07 02 3D 00 9F 08 02 00 02 9F 0D 05 B4 50 84 00 00 9F 0E 05 00 00 00 00 00 9F 0F 05 B4 70 84 80 00 9F 42 02 06 43 9F 4A 01 82 90 00

How generate offline limit transaction using paypass? How to do Generate AC?

Thank you!

Comment: can you make this part more clear - How generate offline limit transaction using paypass?

Answer (score 0):

CDOL1 and CDOL2 splits like below. Tag and its lengths. You are supposed to provide the data alone in the same order and size as you would for PDOL. In the below case, apart from two towards the bottom, rest all are available in the terminal ready to use.

```
CDOL1
9F02    06          //transaction amount
9F03    06          //other amount, cashback
9F1A    02          //termial country
95      05          //TVR terminal has arrived after terminal risk management
5F2A    02          //currency code
9A      03          //Transaction date
9C      01          //transaction type
9F37    04          //unpredictable number
9F35    01          //terminal type
9F45    02          //data Authentication code from Transaction Related Data ODA
9F4C    08          //icc dynamic number from Transaction Related Data ODA
9F34    03          //cvm results

CDOL2
91      0A          //issuer authentication data 
8A      02          //ARC
95      05          //TVR
9F37    04          //unpredictable number
9F4C    08          //icc dynamic number
```

9F26 and 9F36 will be returned by the card in response to your GEN AC.
9F37 is generated by the terminal.